# Can $A^3=0$ imply $|I+A|=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $A$ is a non-zero matrix such that $A^3=0$. Prove the following assertions or provide counter examples:-

$(1) A^2$ is a zero matrix
$(2) A+A^2$ can have zero trace
$(3) A-A^2$ can have zero trace
$(4) I+A$ is  singular.

***My Attempt***:- I know if $A^3=0$ then  $A^2=0$ can be true (though not always). I have no idea whether $tr(A+A^2)=0$ or $tr(A-A^2)=0$ is possible or not if $A^3=0$. But when I looked closely at $|I+A|$ then I found that
$$|I+A|=0$$
For $2\times2$ matrix, we have
$$\Rightarrow |A|+tr(A)+1=0 $$ 
$$\Rightarrow \lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1+\lambda_2+1=0 $$ 
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the two eigenvalues of $A$
$$\Rightarrow \lambda_1(\lambda_2+1)+1.(\lambda_2+1)=0 $$ 
$$\Rightarrow (\lambda_2+1)(\lambda_1+1)=0 $$ 
$$\Rightarrow \lambda_2=-1, \lambda_1=-1  \tag1$$
But we have $$A^3=0$$
$$\Rightarrow |A^3|=0$$
$$\Rightarrow |A|^3=0$$
$$\Rightarrow |A|=0$$
So,
either $\lambda_1=0$ or $\lambda_2=0$ (or both may be zero) which contradicts with equation $(1)$. So, $I+A$ is non singular.

Am I Correct ?

Comment: *Hint to much easier approach for (4):* Consider $(I+A)(I-A+A^2)$

Comment: For (2), (3), _any_ such $A$ you try will show these options can be ruled out. So every example is a counterexample! That is because when $A^3=0$, all eigenvalues of $A$ exist and are equal to zero. Then the same goes for all eigenvalues of the powers $A^k$ of $A$. And the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, and the trace is linear, $\mathrm{tr}(X+Y)=\mathrm{tr}(X)+\mathrm{tr}(Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Your first sentence about option (1) is correct, it can be ruled out. 
Your thoughts about $2\times2$ matrices and option (4) are also correct. 
However, here we might deal with bigger matrices. Especially because for a $2\times2$ matrix $A$, we do have $A^3=0 \implies A^2=0$.

It's generally a good practice to think about examples. A typical example for $A^3=0$ is
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$$
This example rules out options (2) and (3), so we're indeed only left with (4).

For this, can you find an inverse for $I+A$, knowing $A^3=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$(I+A)(I-A+A^2)=I,$$ hence $I+A$ is nonsingular.

For $(2), (3)$, try the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$ can be true, set $A = \pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$.

$A^3 = 0$ implies that $\sigma(A) = \{0\}$, because the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^3$.

This in turn means that $\sigma(A^k) = \{0\}$ so $\operatorname{Tr} A^k = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore $(b)$ and $(c)$ are always true:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(A \pm A^2) = \operatorname{Tr} A \pm \operatorname{Tr} A^2 = 0$$

Also, $\sigma(I + A) = \{1\}$ so $\det(I + A) = 1 \ne 0$, so $(d)$ is certainly false.